# I am unable to locate an element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tblForeground">
                <table id="defaultaccess" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="TOP" align="LEFT" scope="rowgroup">
                            <img width="12" height="12" border="0" alt="" src="/img/8space.gif">
                            <img width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Public Access" src="/img/publicaccess.gif">
                            <a target="info" href="/Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll&amp;objAction=EditAcl&amp;objId=9388&amp;id=9388&amp;rightId=-1&amp;permType=3&amp;nextURL=%2FLivelink%2Flivelink%2Eexe%3Ffunc%3Dll%26objid%3D2000%26objAction%3Dbrowse%26sort%3Dname">Public Access</a>
```

In the above html code of table i want to locate the 'a' tag with text ' Public Acess'. But when I am using the below code it showing an error as i am  unable to locate the element. Here is the following code:

```
WebElement       element1 = driver.findElement(By.className("tblForeground"));
List<WebElement> list1    = element.findElements(By.id("defaultaccess"));

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++)  {
if (list1.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText().equals("Public Access")) {
    list1.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
        break;
    }

}
```

Can you please  help me in  locating the particular element from the above table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to use selenium ide to record locators?

Comment: ya i tried but its not getting
In selenium ide it is showing only assert title

Answer (score 0):

Change following:

```
List<WebElement> list1    = element.findElements(By.id("defaultaccess"));
```

to

```
List<WebElement> list1    = element.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='defaultaccess']/tbody/tr/td"));
```

Since `a` tag is under `table -> tbody -> tr -> td` tag

Comment: Ya sure but its not locating the class name 'tblBackground' itself.

Comment: What error did you get? If it's element `NoSuchElementError` then check if that element is within `iframe`. If it's within `iframe` then first switch to that `iframe` and then find that element

Comment: yeah it is in iframe n i got that ifram and there were no errors and warnings still it is not locating that element....

Comment: i mean i have kept the for loop within the main for loop itself. hence it is not showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Helllo, try this:

```
int nr = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,\"tblForeground\")]/table/tbody/tr")).size();
        for (int i = 1; i <= nr; i++)
        {
            try{
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,\"tblForeground\")]/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td/a[contains(text(),\"Public Access\")]")).click();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            }
        }
```